# Sql unite and sum after join

Tags: sql, oracle

I has Users with id and name, Books with id, title and price and table, who contains users id and books id. It's looks like:
[image]

Im need get table, who has user name and total price spended at books.
I wrote such sql comand:

```
select "USER".name, "BOOK".price from "BOOKTOUSER" inner join "USER" on  
"USER".id = "BOOKTOUSER".USERID inner join "BOOK" on  "BOOK".id = "BOOKTOUSER".BOOKID;
```

As result, i got:
[image]
But i need, that name doesn't repeated and each name has a sum of prices.

Comment: select sum(price) ... GROUP BY name

Comment: I don't know why, but now it's really working.

Answer (score 1):

use group by "USER".name and sum "BOOK".price

```
select USER.name, SUM(BOOK.price) from BOOKTOUSER inner join USER on  
USER.id = BOOKTOUSER.USERID inner join BOOK on  "BOOK".id = BOOKTOUSER.BOOKID
group by USER.name
```

Comment: I think i'm hurry to ask question. Anyway, thanks all for supporting. I'm apreciate that.